# NSString to enum Value (Objc)

Tags: objective-c, enums, nsstring

```
typedef enum {
    red = 10,
    blue = 21,
    white = 32
} colors;
#define ENUMvalue2str(value)   @(#value)
```

I used `ENUMvalue2str(white)` get `@"white"`，
now, I want get `white` from `@"white"`.
not use NSArray, how to do it ?

Comment: `I want get white from @"white"` <- this is not clear to me what you want to achieve.

Comment: You may have answers on https://stackoverflow.com/questions/925991/objective-c-nsstring-to-enum or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7083361/objective-c-convert-string-to-enum or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16844728/converting-from-string-to-enum-in-c

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`enum`s are from pure C. There is no runtime information about the label strings. Therefore it is impossible to translate an instance of an `NSString` into a value of an enumeration label. The only way to do that is to have if cascades.

This is one reason, why I do not use C enumerations, if it is possible. I simply define strings for the label and pass the string itself as argument, if the enum value is simply a marker, an option. If I need a combination of values (aka bit sets) I use instances of `NSSet` with strings.

If your are interested in a specific value of an enumeration (instead of having simply 0, 1, 2, …), you can use dictionaries as explained in the link in the comment to your Q.